# Sephardi (Spanish-Portuguese) siddur

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, s-and-p-sephardi

Is there anywhere where I can find the text of the Spanish nusach online? I can find Sefard and Mizrachi siddurim, but from what I am aware, they vary quite strongly from the old Spanish-Portuguese version, as practiced in Amsterdam and New York (and others of which I am unaware).

Comment: In addition to Yishai's answer, you may want to try contacting the Spanish Portuguese synagogue in NYC or Mikve Israel in Philadelphia and ask which siddur most accurately records that Nusach so you have a title to look for.

Comment: Call rabbi Marc Angel Phone: 212 873 0300 x 205, the sitar used at Shearith Israel in Manhattan.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that [David Aaron deSola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_de_Aaron_de_Sola)'s [siddur](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupname?key=Siddur%20(Spanish%20and%20Portuguese)) is the one that is commonly used today in these communities. It is [available online](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc2.ark:/13960/t89g5rk83;view=1up;seq=1).

Comment: The link for online access is not for a siddur, but a S&P machzor for Yamin Noraim.

Comment: This is for sure the siddur used by the Spanish-Portuguese communities.

Comment: @ezra, knowing your siddur collection, you might find Aryeh's answer, below, interesting.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - I'm surprised you remembered that I collect siddurim. I have seen Aryeh's answer and I _do_ find it interesting!

Comment: @ezra, I wish I knew why I recall what I do about people, maybe if you study psychology, you can tell me. In any case, mine arrived last week and it is beautiful. The nusach is lovely as well, although you need to go to London or Amsterdam to get a real grasp of it.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - So maybe you could briefly explain some things that distinguish it from other nusachos? How does it compare to a general Edot HaMizrach siddur? Does it have post-Arizal kabbalistic additions?

Comment: @ezra, it is significantly less kabbalistic than other Sephardi siddurim. Further, it is closer to North African nusach than 'Iraqi/'Edot haMizrah. It also contains no shiluvim or kavvanot, as these were not written in pre-Lurianic siddurim. S&P also include yotzrot and kerovot on certain occasions, unlike other Sephardim, who follow the Rambam or R' Yitzchak Luria

Answer (score 1):

Koren Publishers have just released a [Humash with Shabbat services](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/new-releases-koren/koren-amsterdam-shabbat-humash.html) according to the S&P rite in Amsterdam.

Info on this unique book:

> The new Koren Amsterdam Shabbat Humash includes the entire Shabbat service from Friday night to Saturday night according to the traditions of the Spanish and Portuguese community of Amsterdam, Kahal Kadosh Talmud Torah. It features the complete tefilla service for Shabbat, full humash and haftarah readings with instructions in both Dutch and English, making this a wonderful contribution to S&P communities throughout the world.

Comment: Why Dutch rather than Spanish or Portuguese?   That seems random.

Comment: @Heshy, the most renowned S&P community is the Amsterdamer Kaal, which speaks Dutch as their "Mammeloschen"

Comment: I have this chumash, but this doesn't answer my OP, which specifies "online"

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be moot by now, but David de Sola Pool's *Book of Prayer* is available on archive.org:

https://archive.org/details/DavidDeSolaPoolSederTefilotBookOfPrayer1960

Kol tuv,

Yaakov

Answer (score 0):

There is also an S&P Birkon app for Android (free), which has Birkat ha mazon, mein shalosh, and a few other prayers.

If you know the specific text you are looking for sometimes its online (e.g. tzur mishelo, etc.).