# Pre-Arizal Sephardi Siddur?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, prayer-book, arizal, nusach-edot-hammizrach

Where can I find a Sephardi siddur with **none** of the Arizal's influences - essentially, a Pre-Ari Sephardi Siddur?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44490/759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look for a British or Dutch Sephardi siddur. After Sabbatai Sbi, the S&P community actively removed all Lurianic and Zoharic emendations to their nusach (source: R' Jonathan Cohen of the London S&P minhagim site)

Comment: I thought S&P stood for Spanish and Portuguese, not Sbritish and Pdutch.

Comment: @msh210, Hahah.

Comment: No, seriously: if the S&P community is what we're looking for, why look for British and Dutch? Is that where all the S&P folks went ca. 1500?

Comment: @msh210, a sizeable enough portion settled in Amsterdam that it became the centre of the S&P community. For some reason, the Sephardim in Bordeaux (who spoke Spanish, not French) and in Italy don't seem to be as well-recognised in what I've read. Further, Amsterdam's K"K Talmud Torah is considered the "cathedral" schul for the S&P communities in London, the US, Caribbean, and Israel.

Comment: Doesn't the Koren-Sacks siddur labeled "Sepharad" follow the Spanish-Portuguese nusach?

Comment: @ezra, my answer where I assert that is wrong. I’m not allowed to delete it, since it’s been accepted for so long. I subsequently got a copy and realized that it’s mainstream Israeli Sfard.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Oy. Sorry for you. GOOD FOR ME! It's strange that they called it "Sepharad" instead of a "Sefard"... Sepharad makes me think of Spain.

Comment: @ezra, it's an Israeli thing.

Answer (score 5):

You could start with the Rambam's [סדר תפילות כל השנה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01999.html#HtmpReportNum0006_L99) found at the end of משנה תורה - ספר אהבה.

The Rambam predates the Arizal by over 300 years.

Comment: This isn't really sefardi Nusach as much as yemenite

Comment: @DoubleAA - was there a difference before the Arizal?

Comment: Of course! They were thousands of miles apart!

Comment: @DoubleAA When Rambam wrote his Mishneh Torah he was head of the Egyptian community. I doubt he wrote the order of prayers for the Yemenites over the Egyptians.

Comment: @aaron that's​ debatable, but anyway it'd just show that the Egyptian rite was more similar to the yemenite rite than the Spanish rite. There used to be more variation than just Ashkenaz and sefardic rites.

Comment: @DoubleAA I do agree with you. Just wanted to make sure because I don't like how the Rambam is written off as "Yemenite," when that was not his target audience for his writings. Everything he did and passed was first and foremost done for his Egyptian community, like his son after him. It's history that paired him and the Yemenites, not his major works.

Comment: @aaron he did happen to live there most of his life, but things may be more complicated than you are presenting. I don't have much reason to think the Egyptian​ community was his first and foremost objective for everything. Great leaders look at the big picture too

Comment: @DoubleAA i agree with you, but I don't think "big picture" meant "only for the Yemenites"

Comment: @Aaron, the Rambam's nusach is very similar to what they already had in Teiman. In Egypt, they used a variant closer to the old Nusach Eretz Yisrael (as attested to in some Cairo Geniza fragments)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt A lot of the Cairo Genizah had all sorts of things that were not necessarily Egyptian either. There are fragments of works that aren't even considered Jewish anymore. In Teiman they followed the Siddurim of the Geonim, Sa'adya and the Rasag I believe.

Comment: @Aaron, Is there a Sa'adya other than the Rasa"g amongst the Geonim?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Sorry, I meant Sa'adyah Gaon and Amram Gaon

Comment: @Aaron, how do we know anything definitive about R' 'Amram Gaon's siddur? None of the recensions bear much similarity to each other and disagree with his commentary and shu"t R' Natronai Gaon (Wikipedia).

Comment: @Aaron - Also the Cairo Genizah has a bunch of stuff from non-Rabbinic Jews, like things from Karaites, etc. not to mention the round tefillin shel yad and gold-plated tefillin, which are blatantly against halacha, even from the Mishnah!